# Free memory after malloc

Tags: c, malloc

i have some code:

```
char * itoa(int a)
{
    char (*t)[16]=(char(*)[16])malloc(1*sizeof(char[16]));
    sprintf(*t,"%d",a);
    return *t;
}
// ...
mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,itoa(i));
```

can i free memory from malloc, without add temporary variables?
e.g:

```
temp=itoa(i);
mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,temp);
free(temp);
```

Comment: To free it, you need a pointer to it, for that you need a variable to hold the pointer. Aside, why `char (*)[16]` and not plain `char*`?

Comment: just as a side note, you shouldn't cast the result of malloc  [do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: This is why `itoa` takes a `char *` as the second argument.

Comment: Well, sort of. It is possible to add conservative garbage collection to C, and then you don't need any explicit calls to free: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: No.

To free allocated memory you need a reference to it.

If you could change your conversion API, a possible work around could be to use an externally provided buffer:

```
char * itoa(char * t, int i)
{
  sprintf(t,"%d",a);
  return t;
}
```

Call `itoa()` this way then:

```
{
  char buffer [16];

  mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,itoa(buffer, i));
}
```

Alternatively (C99 only) one could do the call to `itoa()` this way:

```
mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,itoa((char[16]){0}, i));
```

So to clean up this a macro helps:

```
#define ITOA_0(i) itoa((char[16]){0}, i) /* init array with 0s */
#define ITOA(i) itoa((char[16]){}, i) /* do not init array with 0s -> faster, but none ISO */

...

mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,ITOA(i));
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `malloc` for buffers for which you know that the scope is restricted anyhow.

A good solution for such cases where you might want to keep a buffer for a while are *compound literals* as of C99. I'd go for something like

```
char const* itoa(int a, char (*buffer)[16]) {
    sprintf(*buffer,"%d",a);
    return *buffer;
}

#define ITOA(A) itoa((A), &(char[16]){ 0 })
```

The pointer to array for the function assures that a buffer of `16` elements is passed.

Comment: That's clever as hell; never would have thought to use compound literals in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it, is to alloc a *static* array in the function, this way you won't have to free it at all:

```
const char* itoa(int a)
{
    static char t[16];
    sprintf(t,"%d",a);
    return t;
}

mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,itoa(i));
```

Note:

This way is not thread-safe and cannot be used more than once as an argument to a function.

Comment: It's a possibility but don't forget to mention that it wouldn't work for threaded code or used multiple times in a function call. `mvwprintw(my_menu_win,i+1,2,itoa(i), itoa(j));` would not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

Your `itoa` function compiles by accident.  A pointer to array of `char` is a different type from a pointer to `char`, and this would have thrown a warning but for the fact you're returning `*t` instead of `t`.  Given that `t` has type "pointer to 16-element array of `char`", the expression `*t` has type "16-element array of `char`".  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.  So you're returning the correct type by accident.

You do not need to cast the result of `malloc` (at least as of C89).  Here's a typical template for a `malloc` call:

```
T *p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);
```

where `N` is the number of elements of type `T` you're allocating.  So you could rewrite your call as

```
char *t = malloc(16 * sizeof *t);
```

although in this particular case the `sizeof` is redundant, since `sizeof char` == 1.  Then the rest of your code would be

```
sprintf(t, "%d", a);
return t;
```

Then at some point later on you would call `free` on the value returned by your implementation of `itoa`.  Although frankly Jens Gustedt's solution is better if you're using a C99 or later compiler.